# Remove appendices page in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

i am creating my thesis report in latex.While adding appendices i am getting a page only with a string "Appendices" before Appendix A and Appendix B. The code for the appendix is as follows

```
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{}
   \lhead{Appendix \emph{A}}
  \begin{center}
  \Large {\textbf{BOOK Dataset}}
\end{center}
  \begin{center}
  \large{\textbf{Accuracy of POSITIVE class features}}
  \end{center}

  \begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
  \caption{Accuracy (\%) of unigram features using MI}
  \end{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Feature Length} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{unigram without threshold} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{unigram with threshold} \\ \cline{2-7} 
                                & C1       & C2      & C3      & C1        & C2       & C3       \\ \hline
200                             & 56             & 70.4         & 60.7        & 56.7            & 70.4          & 55.5         \\ \hline
500                             & 60             & \cellcolor{violet!=40}72.4         & 63          & 61.7            & \cellcolor{violet!=40}72.4          & 65.9         \\ \hline
1000                            & 64.2           & 70.8         & 58.6        & 63.6            & 70.7          & 62.8         \\ \hline
1100                            & 65.8           & 71           & 58.6        & 65.3            & 71.6          & \cellcolor{blue!=50}70.4         \\ \hline
1300                            & 65.1           & 72           & 66.1        & 65.8            & 71.6          & 62           \\ \hline
1400                            & 65.7           & 71.4         & 65.2        & 66.7            & 71.3          & 61.4         \\ \hline
1600                            & \cellcolor{green!=50}66.9           & 70.2         & 66.5        & 67.5            & 70.8          & 62.7         \\ \hline
2000                            & 66.3           & 71.5         & \cellcolor{blue!=50}67.7        & \cellcolor{green!=50}68.7            & 70.1          & 61.8         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
  \chapter{}

  \lhead{Appendix \emph{B}}

\begin{center}
  \Large {\textbf{MOVIE Dataset}}
\end{center}
  \begin{center}
  \large{\textbf{Accuracy of POSITIVE class features}}
  \end{center}



 \begin{table}[h]
 \begin{center}
   \caption{Accuracy(\%) unigram features using MI}
 \end{center}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
                                 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Accuracy without threshold}                                            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Accuracy with threshold}                                               \\ \cline{2-7} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Feature Length} & C1                           & C2                           & C3                           & C1                           & C2                           & C3                           \\ \hline
1300                             & 80.5                         & 81.2                         & 81.5                         & 79.6                         & 81.1                         & 80.9                         \\ \hline
1400                             & 79.5                         & 81.6                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFC7}81.8 & 78.2                         & 81.4                         & 81.3                         \\ \hline
1500                             & 79.6                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}81.7 & 81.6                         & 79.1                         & 80.9                         & 80.6                         \\ \hline
1600                             & 80                           & 81                           & 81.1                         & 80.4                         & 81.8                         & 80.9                         \\ \hline
1800                             & 79.6                         & 81                           & 80.6                         & 80.5                         & 80.9                         & 80.8                         \\ \hline
1900                             & 79.7                         & 81.4                         & 80.8                         & 80.6                         & 81.6                         & 82.4                         \\ \hline
2000                             & 79.9                         & 81.5                         & 81.3                         & 79.9                         & 82.5                         & 82.6                         \\ \hline
2100                             & 80.2                         & 80.2                         & 80.3                         & 80.4                         & 82.8                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFC7}83.5 \\ \hline
2300                             & 80.7                         & 80.3                         & 80.5                         & 81.3                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}83.2 & 83.5                         \\ \hline
2400                             & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}80.8 & 80.2                         & 79.9                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}81.4 & 83.1                         & 82.8                         \\ \hline
2500                             & 80.5                         & 80.4                         & 79.8                         & 81                           & 83.1                         & 83.1                         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The main file calling this appendix chapter as follows

```
\input{./Chapters/main_appendix.tex}
```

My problems are :

1.Before the chapter "Appendix A" a page with a word "Appendices" is displaying i want to remove this page.
2.Also in Table of Contents its showing like

- Appendices .................. 45
- Appendix A ...................... 46
- Appendix B ...................... 47

i want to display it with Appendix A and Appendix B. so that remove Appendices ...45

any idea to solve my problems

Comment: Just remove the [`appendix` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix) from your preamble (so says the crystal ball). Of course, then other things might not work as expected. However, in that sense, please update your post with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that also replicates your problem. It'll help us address your problems far more quickly.

Comment: appendix package means..\begin{appendices}???

Comment: No, `appendix` package means `\usepackage{appendix}` *and* `\begin{appendices}`...`\end{appendices}`.

Comment: the Problems are : table of contents shows 9 ....45 and 10 ... 53 and appendix A and Appendix B chapters shows chapter name as chapter 9 and chapter 10

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. Can you click on [this link](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) and provide us with the information needed? It would go a long way in showing us what's going on at your end.

Comment: my codes are already given in the question itself..may i know what are the other information u needed?

Comment: The linked post mentions that you should create a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. The code in your post does not provide this. The `\documentclass` part is important since that sets up many things that are related to the Table of Contents/ToC. Moreover, you may be using other ToC-related packages that influence the way things can be solved. So, please follow this instruction: Recreate your current problem by providing the community with a small document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am puzzled by the `\end{document}` in the `\input`ted file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the [`appendix` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix) with the `[titletoc]` package option. From the [`appendix` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/appendix/appendix.pdf):

> The `appendices` environment can be used instead of the `\appendix`
>    command. [...]
>    The functions of the `appendices` environment are usually accessed through
>    the package options, but there are declarations that may be used instead. 
>    The options are:
>
> - `toc`
>
>   Put a header (e.g., `Appendices`) into the Table
>     of Contents (the ToC) before listing the appendices. (This
>     is done by calling the `\addappheadtotoc` command.)
>
>   [...]
> - `titletoc`
>
>   Adds a name (e.g., `Appendix`) before each
>     appendix listed in the ToC.
>     The name is given by the value of `\appendixname`.
>
>   [...]

Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\chapter{Another chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{}
\chapter{}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how do i remove Appendix A, Appendix B from the table of contents but add only Appendix on the toc

Comment: @kong: Are you also using the [`appendix` package](//ctan.org/pkg/appendix)? How about supplying a minimal example of your current setup, even if it's on [Pastebin](//pastebin.com)?